# i create a welcome email to customer after registering

Tags: marketing-cloud, community

i simply created the email and then i created the triggered send interaction.

**my question is**: after I activate the triggered I will receive the welcome email after every registration or maybe there is a specific code to add or automation?

Comment: Hi Mayla. The Triggered Send requires you to post an API call to it's Triggered Send Definition endpoint. There is a quite comprehensive guide, which explains the concept behind TS emails in SFMC here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/triggered_email_scenario_guide_for_developers.html

Comment: thanks a lot but should i add the API Call in Ampscript?

Comment: Additionally, you can go through this [article](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/25/introduction-to-triggered-sends/) made by Zuzanna Jarczynska to get a better understanding and implementation steps of Triggered Sends. There are different approaches on how to use them and without these details, it is hard to advise besides providing a good reference.